# Translate curl to Javascript ajax code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, curl

How can I translate this curl script to an AJAX request in JavaScript?

```
curl -X POST
     -d "grant_type=password&username=admin&password=Demo1234"
     -u "<ClientID>:<ClientSecret> " http://<host>/url/to/auth
```

Comment: It should be noted that doing this will expose these values to users. In most cases that include a `password` parameter, this is **not a good thing**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `curl` call uses three things:

1. Unprocessed data.
2. HTTP Authentication.
3. Templating? - Not sure.

This is what I best came up with:

```
$.ajax({
  "url": "http://<host>/url/to/auth",
  "data": "grant_type=password&username=admin&password=Demo1234",
  "processData": false,
  "beforeSend": function (xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("<ClientID>" + ":" + "<ClientSecret>"));
  }
});
```

Replace your `<ClientID>` and `<ClientSecret>` with the right values.

Comment: Important to note that you can do this with plain javascript. You don't need to use Jquery although that does make it much easier.

Comment: @richbai90 Yep... Also this method is cross browser... Please note that the author asks for jQuery method in tags. `:)`

Comment: @richbai90 not really, native XHR is arguably better now a days, especially if you can use `fetch`

Comment: @SterlingArcher No support in IE 7! `:)` Remember banks still use IE 6!!!

Comment: @PraveenKumar that's their problem, not mine :) I'm not going to muddle my code for 1-3% of users that refuse to upgrade

Comment: @SterlingArcher Unfortunately, it's we FE Devs are getting pissed off because of them. ps: I work for a company that uses IE 6! `:(`

Comment: Maybe get a new job

Comment: There's far more development jobs out there than there are developers

Comment: @PraveenKumar I now have an issue:

Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I'm trying this in a Wordpress theme. Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

I will show an example in pure `JavaScript`

```
function sendData()
{
    var formData = new FormData(); //create formData object to send data
        formData.append("grant_type, "password"); //via append you add data 
        formData.append("username", "admin"); 
        formData.append("password", "Demo1234");
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); //create "ajax/xhr" object
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() //monitor status of response
        {
            if(xmlHttp.readyState === 4 && xmlHttp.status === 200) //if it's ok
            {
                console.log(xmlHttp.responseText); //then output data
            }
        }
        xmlHttp.open("POST", "http://<host>/url/to/auth"); 
        xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("<ClientID>" + ":" + "<ClientSecret>");
        xmlHttp.send(formData);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do it for **any curl** not just this one:

1. Get postman (https://www.getpostman.com/)
2. follow this to import your curl to postman: https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/collections/data_formats#importing-postman-data
3. follow this to generate a code snippet for the curl you just imported: https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/generate_code_snippets

one of the code snippet exporters is jqueryAjax.

Comment: 3 step is thing useful has made my day xD Thx!